# Null pointer when attempting to POST XML with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am receiving a null pointer exception when attempting to POST an XML document (as a DOMSource) to a service. I have no access to the server side code and am working purely with the client.

```
Document docRequest = ...;
...
Entity<DOMSource> docEntity = Entity.xml(new DOMSource(docRequest));
Invocation.Builder requestBuilder = client.target(endpoint).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
Invocation invoker = requestBuilder.buildPost(docEntity);
String rawResponse = invoker.invoke(String.class);
```

Which causes this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$SourceWriter.writeTo(SourceProvider.java:235)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$SourceWriter.writeTo(SourceProvider.java:196)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:502)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
```

What I have determined thus far is that the provider to produce Source objects (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$SourceWriter) is setting its saxParserFactory and transformerFactory instance variables to null. These values never get set again.

From Jersey source:

```
    private final Factory<SAXParserFactory> saxParserFactory;
    private final Factory<TransformerFactory> transformerFactory;

    public SourceWriter(@Context Factory<SAXParserFactory> spf,
            @Context Factory<TransformerFactory> tf) {
        this.saxParserFactory = spf;
        this.transformerFactory = tf;
    }
```

And the code that causes the NullPointerException:

```
public void writeTo(Source source, Class<?> t, Type gt, Annotation[] as, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException {
...
transformerFactory.provide().newTransformer().transform(source, sr);
```

Can somebody provide some context as to why these fields are not being set to a non-null value?